# How do I to disable mouseleave and mouseenter when input text box is in focus?

Tags: input, hover, focus, blur, mouseleave

Here's the thing.

I have two input boxes. Dog and Cat.
If I hover over Dog, both Dog and Cat become green. Works fine.
If I mouseclick on Dog, both Dog and Cat become yellow. Works fine.
With the Dog in focus, both Dog and Cat should remain yellow, even though I can move my mouse all over the screen.

However, my problem is that with Dog in focus (the I-beam cursor is blinking inside the Dog input box), moving the mouse out of Dog will activate mouseleave. Instead of both Dog and Cat remaining yellow (which is what I want), both Cat and Dog become blue. Then when immediatey I do a mouseover, both Cat and Dog become green. But I want both Cat and Dog to remain yellow if Dog is in focus (i.e., when I-Beam is blinking on and off inside Dog).

Why I want both Dog and Cat to remain yellow all the time that the I-beam is blinking on and off inside Dog is this: after the user has clicked inside the target input box (Dog), he will then use his hands to type on the keyboard. In doing so, he may move the mouse aside and the mouse cursor may move out of the input box Dog. I still want both Dog and Cat to be yellow (like when Dog was clicked upon) so that the user can focus on the two input boxes. Unfortunately, with my code being as it is (see below and also my JSFiddle), I am not getting what I want. Help!?

Here's my code.

## HTML

```
<input type="text" value="Rover" id="dog" />
```

## Javascript

```
$("#dog").focus(function() {
   $("#dog").css("background-color","yellow");
   $("#cat").css("background-color","yellow");
});

$("#dog").hover(function() {
   $("#dog").css("background-color","green");   
   $("#cat").css("background-color","green");    
});

$("#dog").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#dog").css("background-color","blue");   
    $("#cat").css("background-color","blue");      
});


$("#dog").blur(function() {
    $("#dog").css("background-color","white");
    $("#cat").css("background-color","white");
});
```

Here's my jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/frankiekam/A586v/5/

I've tried bind(), unbind() and also not(:hover) in my codes but they don't work. I think it's just me. Need a little help here. Anyone?

Frankie Kam, Malaysia.

Comment: Make .hover/.blur classes; then you can removeClass(.hover) no focus and add it back again on blur.

Comment: Hi Alex! Thanks for the reply. 
You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/frankiekam/A586v/7/
I tried it. I doesn't work.